# How to create a sequelize composite constraint with a local table column and a column present in the foreign key table

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I'm using Sequelize and PostgreSQL to create a node app and get stuck in this problem. I have three models in sequelize which are:

1. `BoxTemplate`
2. `BoxTemplateWorkspace`
3. `Workspace`

The model `BoxTemplateWorkspace` is a Many to many association that links many `BoxTemplate` to many `Workspace`. What I'm trying to do is to create a composite unique constraint inside the `BoxTemplate` model, interconnecting a column **Title** in my BoxTemplate with a column **WorkspaceCode** which is inside my BoxTemplateWorkspace.

I already know how to create a composite unique constraint with normal columns and with FK columns that reside in the same table/model. But I'm not able to get through this.

Bellow my code to get a better understanding

### BoxTemplate.js

```js
var boxTemplate = sequelize.define('BoxTemplate', {
        ID: {
            type: DataTypes.UUIDV4,
            defaultValue: sequelize.literal('gen_random_uuid()'),
            allowNull: false,
            primaryKey: true,
            unique: title_WorkspaceCode_unique
        },
        Title: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING(150),
            allowNull: false,
            unique: true
        },
        //... more columns
    }, {
        indexes: [{
            unique: 'title_WorkspaceCode_unique',
            fields: ['Title', /*here should fit the WorkspaceCode present in BoxTemplateWorkspace*/]
        }],
        createdAt: 'CreatedDate',
        updatedAt: 'LastUpdate',
        timestamps: true,
        underscored: false,
        freezeTableName: true,
    });

    boxTemplate.associate = models => {
        // model that makes a many to many relationship
        boxTemplate.hasMany(models.BoxTemplateWorkspace, {foreignKey: 'BoxTemplateCode'});
    }
    
    return boxTemplate;
};
```

### BoxTemplateWorkspace

```js
var boxTemplateWorkspace = sequelize.define('BoxTemplateWorkspace', {
        ID: {
            type: DataTypes.UUIDV4,
            defaultValue: sequelize.literal('gen_random_uuid()'),
            allowNull: false,
            primaryKey: true,
            unique: true
        },
        IsActive: {
            type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
            defaultValue: true,
            allowNull: false
        },
        InactivatedDate: {
            type: DataTypes.DATE,
        },
    },{
        timestamps: false,
        underscored: false,
        freezeTableName: true
    });

    boxTemplateWorkspace.associate = models => {
        boxTemplateWorkspace.belongsTo(models.BoxTemplate, { foreignKey: 'BoxTemplateCode' });

        // column that I want to use as a composite unique constraint
        boxTemplateWorkspace.belongsTo(models.Workspace, { foreignKey: 'WorkspaceCode' });
        boxTemplateWorkspace.belongsTo(models.UserSK, { foreignKey: 'InactivatedByUserCode' });
    }
    return boxTemplateWorkspace;
};
```

As suggested here the UserSK and Workspace Models

### UserSK.js

```js
var userSk = sequelize.define('UserSK', {
        ID: {
            type: DataTypes.UUIDV4,
            defaultValue: sequelize.literal('gen_random_uuid()'),
            allowNull: false,
            primaryKey: true,
            unique: true
        },
        Email: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING(320),
            allowNull: false,
            unique: true
        },
        UserName: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING(150),
            allowNull: false,
            unique: true
        },
    }, {
        createdAt: 'CreatedDate',
        updatedAt: 'LastUpdate',
        timestamps: true,
        underscored: false,
        freezeTableName: true
    });

    userSk.associate = models => {

        userSk.hasMany(models.BoxTemplate, {foreignKey: 'CreatedByUserCode'});
        userSk.hasMany(models.BoxTemplate, {foreignKey: 'UpdatedByUserCode'});
    }
    return userSk;
```

### Workspace.js

```js
var workspace = sequelize.define('Workspace', {
        ID: {
            type: DataTypes.UUIDV4,
            defaultValue: sequelize.literal('gen_random_uuid()'),
            allowNull: false,
            primaryKey: true,
            unique: true
        },
        InvitedDate: {
            type: 'TIMESTAMP',
            defaultValue: sequelize.literal('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'),
            allowNull: true
        },
        WorkspaceName: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING(100),
            allowNull: true
        }
    }, {
        timestamps: false,
        underscored: false,
        freezeTableName: true
    });

    workspace.associate = models => {
        workspace.hasMany(models.BoxTemplateWorkspace, {foreignKey: 'WorkspaceCode'});
    }

    return workspace;
};
```

Comment: Just in case I suggest adding the workspace model, UserSk model, and also are you using sequelize-cli?.

Comment: thanks I will add it, but I don't think it will be much usefull to the problem. And yes, I am using sequelize-cli